# check this query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database

when i run this query it gives this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN reservation rs ON r.restaurant_id = rs.restaurant_id
>                    ' at line 7

and the query is

```
SELECT r.`restaurant_id`,r.`restaurant_name`,r.`capacity`,rs.`start_time`,rs.`end_time`,rs.`people`,rs.`date`,r.`capacity` - SUM(rs.`people`) AS available
            FROM `restaurant` r,


                LEFT JOIN reservation rs ON r.restaurant_id = rs.restaurant_id
               AND <'2015-07-30'> = rs.`date`
              AND <'2:00' >= rs.`end_time`
              AND <'3:00'> = rs.`start_time`
            GROUP BY r.`restaurant_id`
```

please tell me where i did mistake

Comment: Remove comma`,`  Ur second line should be `from restaurant r LEFT JOIN..`

Comment: The errors here a more fundamental than a mere typo (although that is the cause of the present error message).  For instance, which rs.start_time do you want? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your sql. Before left join their is a comma please remove that.

```
SELECT 
r.restaurant_id,r.restaurant_name,r.capacity,rs.start_time,rs.end_time,rs.people,rs.date,r.capacity - SUM(rs.people) AS available FROM restaurant r

                LEFT JOIN reservation rs ON r.restaurant_id = rs.restaurant_id
               AND '2015-07-30' = rs.`date`
              AND '2:00' = rs.`end_time`
              AND '3:00' = rs.`start_time`
            GROUP BY r.`restaurant_id`
```

Thank you.

Comment: You satisfy my answer can you give a tick mark please.

Comment: just  remove angular brakets '<>'

Answer (score 0):

I did not work with MySQL long time, only PL/SQL, but i do not think, that there si comma in "FROM `restaurant` r," try "FROM `restaurant` r"